# i want to use multi select with bootstrap also called chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

I am sonal goyal . New in designing . I want to use multiple select also called 'chosen' in my html page. But enable to create code.
I am using:
1- bootstrap 3.0

2- jquery 1.10.3

In future backbone.js

I find this link [chosen](http://alxlit.github.io/bootstrap-chosen/).but enable to find code.
can you pls help me.

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!-- Build your select: -->
<select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
<option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
<option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
<option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
<option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
<option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
<option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>

<!-- Initialize the plugin: -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.multiselect').multiselect();
});
</script>
```

Ref: http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

Comment: Thanx  you got my question. but its not working. May b i m using wrong approach . can you pls give me more detail or jfiddle. sorry for inconvenience   ...  :(

Comment: thanks chinnu.. i got the result . Your code was right . that time i made mistake in linking

Answer (score 2):

The code is on github if this is what you're asking > https://github.com/alxlit/bootstrap-chosen  Make sure and check "example.html"

Comment: I give an example of functionality for what i want. now i want code for chosen ...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand you :-) What about "Chinnu R" answer, is it good ? Was that what you're looking for ?